# Best way/pattern to select items from SectionList and sync it with Redux state? (see text for details)

Tags: json, react-native, react-redux, react-native-sectionlist

I'm dealing with a huge Json with atleast two levels. Something like:

```
{
 mainkey1: {subkey1: [data array], subkey2: [data array]}, 
 mainkey2: {subkey1: [data array], subkey2: [data array]}
//... More like this
}
```

I am displaying it with a section list for now. Section header is mainkey1 and Items in that section are the keys in that object i.e. subkey1

Now I am trying to Come up with the following behaviour - when user taps the section header/title then all items of that section get selected, their color changes and they get stored in a redux state. Now note that I want the data arrays to be stored as well for use.

In case all items of that section are already selected, they should get deselected and removed from redux state.

Also, when an item is tapped only that item should be selected, color changed and stored in redux state. If an item is already selected, then tapping should deselect it and remove it from redux state.

Items in different sections may have same name.